# Annotations Specification in Java Class File format?

Tags: java, bytecode, .class-file

I am reading Java Virtual Machine Specification second edition for Java 6. But I found it no annotation detail for Java Class File Format. Although the jvm 6 can recognise the annotation.
another question is there also like other feathers like ACC_BRIDGE flag not mention in Virtual machine Specification second edtion but appeared in Java 7 Virtual machine Specification. Tell me why? those features seems like accept by JVM 6 But why didn't metion it in java 6 specification. What I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All JVM internals are documented in [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) and corresponding updates:

- [JVM spec for Java before version 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html)
- [Spec updates for Java 5 VM](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr924/index.html)
- [Spec updates for Java 6 VM](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr924/index2.html)

More specifically, the ACC_BRIDGE flag been introduced in Java 5. See Section 4.7 of the [updated Class File Format](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr924/JVMS-SE5.0-Ch4-ClassFile.pdf).

Comment: Thanks I track down the oracle site for a while. But only found in Java 7 Spec. Thank you for help me found these information.